# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "string", expecting variable in /var/www/vendor/sebastian/version/src/Version.php on line 24

Tags: laravel, docker

Перепробовал много чего и добавление в composer.json команд и различные команды вводил рыская в гугле ничего не помогло, без моих команд запускает спокойно и выдаёт базовый шаблон Laravel, следовательно где-то у меня ошибка в созданных файлах создал проект laravel по классике через консоль было решено чтобы проект запускался через docker

создал docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
      nginx:
        image: nginx:latest
        volumes:
          - ./:/var/www
          - ./_docker/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
        ports:
          - "8876:80"
        depends_on:
          - app
        container_name: shop_nginx
    
      app:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: _docker/app/Dockerfile
        volumes:
          - ./:/var/www
        container_name: shop_app
        depends_on:
          - db
    
      db:
        image: mysql:8.0
        restart: always
        volumes:
          - ./tmp/db:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            MYSQL_DATABASE: shop
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        ports:
          - 8101:3306
        command: mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_unicode_ci
        container_name: shop_db
    
    nginx: server {
    
        root /var/www/public;
        error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    
        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php;
        }
    
        location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_pass app:9000;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           include fastcgi_params;
           fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
           fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
    
    }
    
    Dockerfile: FROM php:8.0-fpm
    
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
          apt-utils \
          libpq-dev \
          libpng-dev \
          libzip-dev \
          zip unzip \
          git && \
          docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && \
          docker-php-ext-install bcmath && \
          docker-php-ext-install gd && \
          docker-php-ext-install zip && \
          apt-get clean && \
          rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
    
    COPY ./_docker/app/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php.ini
    
    # Install composer ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1 RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- \
        --filename=composer \
        --install-dir=/usr/local/bin
    
    WORKDIR /var/www
    
    php.ini : cgi.fix_pathinfo=0 max_execution_time = 1000 max_input_time
    = 1000 memory_limit=4G
    
    composer.json :
              "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
                "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
            }
        },
        "autoload-dev": {
            "psr-4": {
                "Tests\\": "tests/"
            }
        },
        "scripts": {
            "post-autoload-dump": [
                "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
                "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
            ],
            "post-update-cmd": [
                "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
            ],
            "post-root-package-install": [
                "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
            ],
            "post-create-project-cmd": [
                "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
            ]
        },
        "extra": {
            "laravel": {
                "dont-discover": []
            }
        },
        "config": {
            "optimize-autoloader": true,
            "preferred-install": "dist",
            "sort-packages": true,
            "allow-plugins": {
                "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
                "php-http/discovery": true
            }
        },
        "minimum-stability": "stable",
        "prefer-stable": true }
```

я даже не особо понимаю какую инфу с проекта выкладывать чтобы поняли в чем проблема.

Comment: по новой создал проект на докере выдаёт ошибку : Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 8.0.28. in /var/www/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24, при решении проблемы которые предоставляет гугл возвращает к моей проблеме

Comment: В вашем же комментарии написано что нужна версия PHP 8.1 или выше, у вас же 8.0.28. `Dockerfile: FROM php:8.0-fpm`, чего Вы ожидаете?

Comment: FROM php:8.2.4-fpm всё равно не фурычит

Comment: "Не фурычит" -- понятие растяжимое.

Comment: пробовал изменял, всё равно таже ошибка

Comment: Та же это: `Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0`?